# R code to assign a sequence based off of multiple variables

Tags: r, loops, group-by, sequence

I have data structured as below:

```
ID   Day   Desired Output
1    1      1
1    1      1
1    1      1
1    2      2
1    2      2
1    3      3
2    4      1
2    4      1
2    5      2
3    6      1
3    6      1
```

Is it possible to create a sequence for the desired output without using a loop? The dataset is quite large so a loop won't work, is it possible to do this with the dplyr package or maybe a combination of cumsum/diff?

Comment: Isn't the expected column same as `Day` Try `df1  %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(desired = match(Day, unique(Day)))`

Comment: @akrun Sorry I definitely messed the day numbers up... I edited it to the correct numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to group by 'ID', and then do a `match` on the 'Day' with the `unique` values of 'Day' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(desired = match(Day, unique(Day)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```